# Ligatures for helvetica font

Tags: ligatures

I am using helvetica {phv} as secondary font in one of my project.

In that I need fi and fl ligatures on.

Can anyone help me how to keep the liguatures on.

Thanks

S. Vinay

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which TeX engine -- pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, or something else? -- and which TeX format -- plain TeX, LaTeX2e, or something else? -- do you use?

Comment: Imho phv hasn't these ligatures, tex gyre heros (qhv) has an ff ligature.

Comment: "True" Helvetica, though not the `phv` close, does have the ligatures `fi` and `fl`. However, they look virtually the same as the unligated character pairs `fi` and `fl` do. For sure, the glyphs are *not* joined in their ligated forms.

Comment: Ligatures are decided by the font designer; some fonts need them, some fonts don't. A known case is Palatino, which was purposely designed not to need f-ligatures; most sans serif fonts have no need for ligatures.